# Is There any way for style for specific control by name in wpf

Tags: wpf, styles

Set control color via resource.

in resource file:

```
<style TargetType="{x:Name button1}">
      <setter Property="ColorBrush" Value="Red"/>
</style>
<Window .... >
    <Button Name="Button1" Content="Test Button" />
</Window>
```

like css in html

```
 <style>
       #controlID
       {
         color:red;
       }
    </style>
<body>
      <input id="button1" type="button" value="test button" />
</body>
```

Comment: Apply the style explicitly to specific button

Comment: Dear  Sriram Sakthivel, i want to have two collection of text for my controls in two seperate resource files for multilingual application. if i change the resource file the language change. is there any way to do this without set static resource key for controls to prevent spend my time.

Answer (score 9):

Define a Style like this in window.resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="btnStyleRed" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
```

and use this style only on those button to which you want to apply particular style

```
<Button x:Name="btnLogin" Style="{StaticResource btnStyleRed}" Content="Login" Width="75" />
```

Comment: This still requires a static resource.